# Is there a list of all the UIApperance traits for each control/view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

So if we want to make all UIButtons have a red background, we can use `UIButton.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red`.

This is great and really convenient, but I'm wondering if there's a list of all the different traits/options we can modify for each control. I know I can type `UIButton.appearance().` and find what I'm looking for from the auto complete but the problem is that it shows all the class members/functions. It'd be nice to see just the ones that relate to the appearance() call.

I tried searching but couldn't find anything, hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: What do you need such a list for? Do you want to achieve anything specific? You can customize nearly everything about a button. Somethings are more complicated than settings a property, though.

Comment: @idmean That's the thing, I don't know what I want to customize. If I saw a list of what I could change, it would give me ideas. Also, it's not exclusive to buttons, it would be great to have that list for all views and controls, or at least the most commonly used ones.

Comment: It is a shame the reference documentation doesn't indicate which attributes can be used with UIAppearance just like they do for indicating whether a property can be animated or not.